# Why it is not possible to for-loop a list of numbers and increment each number directly?

Tags: python

Why will the following code increment each number:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for number in numbers:
    numbers[numbers.index(number)] += 100

print(numbers) # prints [101, 201, 301]
```

but this will not?:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for number in numbers:
    number += 100

print(numbers) # prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Adding to the confusion, we seem to be dealing with same object in both cases:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for number in numbers:
    print(numbers[numbers.index(number)] is number) # prints True
```

I understand this has "something" to do with assigning vs mutating a value and/or memory allocation, but I cannot put my finger on what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers[x]` is just a different syntax for `numbers.__getitem__(x)` (when used as an rvalue) or `numbers.__setitem__(x, y)` (when used as an lvalue).

So in your first example, the `__setitem__()` method of the numbers lists is called to update the list. Under the hood your code is roughly translated to something like this:

```py
for number in numbers:
    index = numbers.index(number)
    new_value = numbers.__getitem__(index) + 100
    numbers.__setitem__(index, new_value)
```

Note that above code is valid Python and has the same effect as your original loop.

In your second example, the values are retrieved from the list and stored in a local variable `number`, which you then overwrite. This has no effect on the original list.

---

NB: Also note that comparing integers using `is` may lead to unexpected behaviour. See for example [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) for more details about that.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as thus:

```
for number in numbers:
```

is roughly the same as:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    number = numbers[i]
```

Now, in the second case it becomes more obvious that adding

```
    # number += 100  # which is not a mutation, but a rebinding equivalent to
    number = number + 100
```

simply reassigns the variable `number` and that `numbers[i]` is and should be unaffected. This holds for the first loop variant, too.

Comment: Addition: if possible, then `__iadd__`/`+=` is implemented such that it mutates the object. See lists, where `+=` is equivalent to `extend`.